# SonarLint connected mode error in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2016.2), I installed the SonarLint plugin and when I try to connect to a SonarQube server I get this error: "The following plugins do not meet the required minimum versions, please upgrade them: php (installed: 2.6, minimum: 2.7)".

I searched for a PHP plugin in IntelliJ but I couldn't find any.

Is it some compatibility issue with the latest IntelliJ versions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PHP plugin needs to be updated in the SonarQube server to which you are connecting, not in Intellij.
You can find it here: [https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPHP](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/PHP+Plugin)